# c# cant add event with specified datetime in google calendar

Tags: c#, google-api

I am trying to create an c# application which can add event on my calendar using GData API

I am trying to figure out how to insert date and time to this event which I create. For now I can create the event but by default it takes the current date and time. I would like to add future event using datetimepicker.

I found somewhere on google developer forum that uses atomentryobj.times but it doesn't work.

Could you please help.

CODE :

```
     EventEntry adder = new EventEntry();
     adder.Title.Text = txt1.txt;
     adder.Content.Content = txt2.txt;
     Where Loc = new Where();
     Loc.ValueString = txt3.txt;
     adder.Locations.Add(Loc);
     When eTime = new When(dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);
     adder.Times.Add(eTime);
 Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myemail/private/full");
        AtomEntry added = service.Insert(postUri, adder);
```

Thank you,
ms

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar V2 API is deprecated, I suggest you move to V3 calendar API, as any time Google will withdraw support to V2.

for starter you can refer : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/